# Wiring old speakers

Tags: materials

I have taken old speakers I found lying around and connected them to a 3.5mm auxiliary connection, however when I plug this into my laptop/phone the sound comes through just really quiet and sometimes only the bass. How can I get the speakers working more efficiently/louder? I'm assuming the Auxiliary connection that I took from old broken earphones is causing the problem, can I get something better?

Comment: i don't know why this is on engineering stackexchange ? or what you are actually trying to accomplish or learn, but no doubt a set of cheap amplified computer speakers will be as good or better than a low end amp and some random speakers you found lying about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need an amplifier of some sort : stereo and after that the choice is huge.

Comment: I've been trying to find just an amplifier but I am not having much luck, is there something specific Im looking for?

Comment: It may be the 3.5mm jack connection.  I have an older computer speaker that gives very low sound unless the jack is at a pretty specific angle (and the right tension in the wire to actually force the loose contact to connect).  There's a (potentially small) chance OP can play with the contacts until it works.

Comment: Search sites like bay of fleas or electronic stores for amplifiers , smaller ones are commonly headphone amps , also there are amplifier kits as well and the power goes up 10w , 50 w etc